# Is there a setting or workaround in gFortran to the Microsoft Fortran 5.1 $STORAGE Metacommand

Tags: fortran, gfortran

We have some (a huge libray or 40+ modules) old Fortran code than needs updating and compiling with a more recent compiler.

Is there anyway to set gFortran  to allow for the $STORAGE:2 metacommand as used by old MS Fortran 5.1?

According to: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/51471

> The $STORAGE:n metacommand allocates "n" bytes of memory for all INTEGER and LOGICAL variables. For example, when an application specifies the $STORAGE:2 metacommand and declares an INTEGER variable B, the compiler allocates two bytes for B instead of four. The $STORAGE metacommand does not affect memory allocation when a declaration includes an explicit length specification, such as an INTEGER*2 or INTEGER*4.

I wish it was a simple matter of rewriting the variable declarations to use integer*2. However the programmer who wrote it, uses tons of implicit variable declarations and many EQUIVALENCE statements everywhere that are troublesome to deal with:

```
$STORAGE:2
    CHARACTER*2 ABC
    EQUIVALENCE (ABC,ITT)
```

Comment: Updating a more recent compiler and you chose g77? Surely you are joking.

Comment: Ok, Could use another ... recommendations of free ones?

Comment: Gfortran, but forget 2 byte default integers. You can promote to 8 by a command line switch, but AFAIK not downgrade.

Comment: Ya, that's the problem .. the original code uses a lot of Equivalence statements where the euivalated var is a 2 byte int: 
CHARACTER*2 ABC
EQUIVALENCE (ABC,ITT)

Comment: You must rewrite the code to use integer*2.

Comment: So ...  CHARACTER*2 ABC INTEGER*2 ITT EQUIVALENCE (ABC,ITT)

Comment: yes, that should do it

Comment: Golly, this is going to be a huge task, the pgmr has 40 source files in the libs that all need converting. Never mind his horrible gotos everywhere and no control loops ...

Answer (score 2):

There is no way I know in modern compilers to do this for 16 bit integers.

Compilers usually allow promoting integer kinds by a command line switch, but I don't recall any modern free compiler to allow a change to 16 bit ones.

I would suggest rewriting the variable declarations to use `integer*2` instead instead of the directive.

Comment: Or if one is switching to a newer compiler such as a non-ancient gfortran, one could use INTEGER(kind=INT16), where INT16 is defined in the ISO_FORTRAN_ENV module. OTOH, INTEGER*2 might be better if it allows the code to be compiled with the old compiler, so one can verify that everything works during the transition phase..

Comment: I really did not want to start mixing his FORTRAN77 (with extensions) and Fortran 2008, but it is certainly possible.

Comment: The problem stems from the fact that the dev uses an obsecene amount of EQUIVALENCE statements to relate char flags to Integer*2 values.